# Aggregate in sql with and without join

Tags: sql

This is what I have so far. The value that I get from SUM is much higher with join than what I get without join.I can't figure out why is that?

```
 SELECT 
  SUM(ingrn.passed_qty)
  FROM
  erp.fabric_grn ingrn
  LEFT JOIN
  erp.fabric_outgrn outgrn 
  ON
  UPPER(ingrn.fab_id) = outgrn.out_id
  GROUP BY ingrn.fab_id
```

It gives a different value from:

```
 SELECT 
  SUM(ingrn.passed_qty)
  FROM
  erp.fabric_grn ingrn
  GROUP BY UPPER(ingrn.fab_id)
```

Comment: Is there a one to many relationship between fabric_grn and fabric_outgrn?

Comment: @dannmate: Yes, that's true. There is .Actually there could be x number of rows for a given id in ingrn and y in outgrn. Can't be defined as such

Comment: That's why you are seeing different results of your sums.

Comment: But I am taking sum only for ingrn.passed_qty. Why should that change it? It is still grouped only by ingrn.fab_id. Could you please help me understand?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a total of the whole dataset you are returning.

Example:

```
Table: fabric_grn
fab_id | passed_qty
1        10

Table: fabric_outgrn
fab_id | another_column
1        xyz
1        zyx
```

For example if you did your first query on the above data: it would return the sum of 10.

But since you are left joining on fabric_outgrn in your second query, it returns **two** rows. Which will be 10+10 = 20.

This is why you are seeing differences.